# If $a\bmod{m}$ has an inverse x, and if $b\bmod{m}$ has an inverse y, prove that $ab\bmod{m}$ has an inverse xy?

Tags: number-theory

If $a\bmod{m}$ has an inverse x, and if $b\bmod{m}$ has an inverse y, prove that $ab\bmod{m}$ has an inverse xy?

Well knowing that $a\bmod{b}$ has an inverse when there exists an $i$ such that $ai\equiv 1\pmod{m}$

Here is what i think

$a\dot{}x=1(\mod{m})$ and $b\dot{}y=1(\mod{m})$ if we multiply both:
$a\dot{}x\dot{}b\dot{}y=1(\mod{m})$ from here on, 
$$ab\dot{}xy=1(\mod{m})$$
Would this actually prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proof is correct, assuming that you already know that such multiplication of congruences is valid, i.e. presuming known the Congruence Product Rule below. Recall also that inverses are necessarily *unique:* $ $ if $\,a,a'\,$ are inverses of $\,b\,$ then $\,a' = a'(ba) = (a'b)a = a.$

---

Below are proofs of common congruence rules. They state, essentially, that the equivalence relation of congruence is *compatible* with the (ring) operations '$+$' and '$*$'), i.e. the result of the operation does not depend upon which equivalence class representatives one chooses for its arguments.

**Congruence Sum Rule** $\rm\qquad\quad  A\equiv a,\quad B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{A+B\,\equiv\, a+b}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a) + (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#0a0}{A+B - (a+b)} $

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a,\ \ and \ \  B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{AB\equiv ab}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A\!-\!a,\ B\!-\!b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A\!-\!a)\ B + a\ (B\!-\!b)\ =\ \color{#c00}{AB - ab} $

**Congruence Power Rule** $\rm\quad\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ A^n\equiv a^n\ \  (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\ $ It is true for $\rm\,n=1\,$ and $\rm\,A\equiv a,\ A^n\equiv a^n \Rightarrow\, A^{n+1}\equiv a^{n+1},\,$ by the Product Rule, so the result follows by induction on $\,n.$

**Beware** $ $ that such rules need not hold true for other operations, e.g.
the exponential analog of above $\rm A^B\equiv a^b$ is not generally true (unless $\rm B = b,\,$ so it reduces to the Power Rule, so follows by inductively applying $\,\rm b\,$ times the Product Rule).

Comment: Well i just found a combination where that product rule does not seem to apply: 17=2 mod3 and 26=2 mod3 but 17*26!=2*2 mod3 as it is 442 = 1mod3

Comment: @user122673 But $\ 2\cdot 2\equiv 1\pmod{3}.\ $ The product rule is true, see the above simple proof.